# PhpStorm - Can't add a theme

Tags: php, themes, phpstorm, color-scheme

I'm student and I got the free latest version of PhpStorm 9 (build PS-141.1912). I tried to add a theme and color scheme to PhpStorm so I put my theme (.icls file) in the `C:\Users\me\.WebIde90\colors` folder:

[image]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/31/1438494561-sans-titre.png))</sub>

Then I restarted PhpStorm, but I can't see my theme:

[image]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/31/1438494462-sans-titre.png))</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on your screenshot and your info, you have placed them in `~\.WebIde90\colors` while it should be **`~\.WebIde90\config\colors`** (where `~` is your user home folder -- typically `C:\Users\USERNAME`).

---

**In general:**
A file with Color Schema (`*.icls`) should be put into appropriate folder and then IDE should be restarted if it was running by that time (as such stuff gets checked only on launch).

- Windows: `C:\Users\USERNAME\.IDE_FOLDER\config\colors`
- Linux: `~/.IDE_FOLDER/config/colors`
- Mac: `~/Library/Preferences/IDE_FOLDER/colors`

Where `IDE_FOLDER` is the `<ProductName><Version>` -- e.g. `PhpStorm2016.2` for the latest stable version of PhpStorm (2016.2.2).

More info on folders: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

**P.S.**
If Color Schema comes as `*.jar` file then use `File | Import Setting...`

---

**Please also note** that these editor themes are for syntax highlighting mainly and can be changed at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts`.

This has nothing to do with GUI Theme (also known as LAF -- Look and Feel -- styling the actual GUI elements) which is a separate thing and available at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`.

**P.S.**
Instead of going into Settings/Preferences .. you can use `View | Quick Switch Scheme...` to quickly change between various schemas (colors/keymaps/code styles/etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution solved my problem. I had this `~\.WebIde90\colors` folder created, so i put my files in this wrong folder.

Comment: so how did you add the theme after that? I am wondering myself

Comment: @LazyOne - i finally found the option via the settings/preferences route - deleted my original comment

Answer (score 17):

In PhpStorm 2016.1 it will be `~\.PhpStorm2016.1\config\colors` (where `~` is your user home folder - typically `C:\Users\USERNAME`).