# How to add new theme in PhpStorm 10.0.1

Tags: phpstorm, text-editor

**Note:** Answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768965/phpstorm-cant-add-a-theme) did not work for me.

I am new to PhpStorm, and I'm currently using the version 10.0.1.

I'm trying to add a new theme [Dark Peacock](http://www.phpstorm-themes.com/theme/dark-peacock-0) because it best suits my preference. I did my research and already tried placing the files in these folders:

```
C:/Users/USERNAME/.PhpStorm2016.1/colors
C:/Users/USERNAME/.PhpStorm10.0.1/colors
C:/Users/USERNAME/.PhpStorm 10.0.1/colors
C:/Users/USERNAME/.WebIde100/config/colors
C:/Users/USERNAME/~/.PhpStorm10.0.1/colors
C:/Users/USERNAME/~/.PhpStorm 10.0.1/colors
```

... but nothing seems to work for me. The new theme just doesn't show up in `File->Settings->->Appearance & Behavior->Appearance->Theme Dropdown`.

Any other idea out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have confused "theme" with "color scheme".

**The theme** is the one that changes the general look of the application, that is, the background color of borders, sidebars, menus, and maybe more (of which I haven't discovered yet). This was not really what I wanted to change.

**The color scheme** is the one that changes the text editor's background and text colors. And this is what I was trying to change.

Color schemes do not show up in

```
File->Settings->->Appearance & Behavior->Appearance->Theme Dropdown
```

because they are in

```
File->Settings->->Editor->Colors & Fonts->Scheme Dropdown
```

> **NOTE:** The exact location for **Dark Peacock.icls** that made this work is:
>
> ```
> C:/Users/USERNAME/.WebIde100/config/colors
> ```
>
> The `colors` folder does not exist, so I had to create it.