# Windows 10 PhpStorm 2016.2.1 can't install new theme

Tags: themes, phpstorm

I've downloaded a theme file for PhpStorm from phpstorm-themes.com, one is a xml file and the other is a icls file.

On the Help section, is said that I have to place the file into /config/colors, but I don't have these folders into my phpstorm folder (~\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2016.2.1)...

Can anyone help? Thanks

EDIT

I've followed this post [PhpStorm - Can't add a theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768965/phpstorm-cant-add-a-theme)

BUT, my PhpStorm folder does not have a config or a config/colors folder.
I tried to create those for myself, but even so, after restarting PhpStorm, when I go to Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Import, the resulting pop-up says that's "nothing to show"

[image]

Comment: *"Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Import"* What `Import`?? Screenshot please of that "import". What OS do you have there?

Comment: @LazyOne I'm using windows 10 and PhpStorm 2016.2.1. I've posted a image in my question

Comment: OK -- 2016.3.2 does not have such "Import" button. If you are on Windows 10 and using 2016.2 version .. then the path where to put your color schema (`.icls` file) would be `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStorm2016.2\config\colors`

Comment: You have created `Dacrula jose` theme (a copy of Darcula, I guess). Just close IDE and search you disk (home folder in particular) for a file names `Darcula jose.icls` (or just `darcula*.*` to start with)